# Is it possible to run Mask RCNN Object detection model on Raspberry Pi 4 device?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4

I need to implement the mask-rcnn model on the raspberry pi 4 device, I tried converting the pre-trained Matterport model to TensorFlow lite but getting runtime error so I'm confused whether Mask-RCNN models are compatible with Raspberry Pi 4 or not? And is it possible to directly run the TensorFlow Mask-RCNN model without converting it to tfLite?

Comment: Hi Aman, please clarify a few things: Where are you getting the pretrained model from? what code are you using to convert it to Tensorflow? What error are you getting? Can you share some code that we can run to reproduce the error?

Comment: The question is still unclear. Voting to close.

Comment: @ibarrond Sorry for the delay( was on leave). Actually, I'm trying to run an object detection model on Raspberry Pi, firstly I implemented the Tensorflow lite SSD sample model and it worked fine on the device then I tried to implement Mask RCNN model on Raspberry Pi then I got this error -- RuntimeError: Regular TensorFlow ops are not supported by this interpreter. Make sure you apply/link the Flex delegate before inference.Node number 363 (FlexCropAndResize) failed to prepare. -- On Tensoflow website they have mentioned we are under development and Rapberry pi supports 32bit OS.